# код вставляет элементы списка, а не сам список

Tags: python, list

Помогите задачку решить.... Мой код вставляет элементы списка, а не сам список, и я не знаю, как это исправить.

На вход программе подаются две строки, на одной символы, на другой число nn. Из первой строки формируется список.

Реализуйте функцию chunked(), которая принимает на вход список и число, задающее размер чанка (куска), а возвращает список из чанков указанной длины.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подается строка текста, содержащая символы, отделенные символом пробела и число nn на отдельной строке.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести указанный вложенный список.

Есть код, но работает некорректно..

```
def chunked():
    e = input().split(' ')
    t = int(input())
    r = []
    u = []
    for j in range(len(e)):
        r.append(e[j])
        if len(r) == t:
            u.extend(r)
            r.clear()
    if len(e) % t != 0:
        u.extend([r])
    print(u)          
    print(a)
    
chunked()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_list.asp

```
append()    Adds an element at the end of the list
extend()    Add the elements of a list (or any iterable), to the end of the current list
```

---

```
    if len(r) == t:
        u.append(r)
        r = []
```

Comment: Честно, я не знаю, как ответить тому, кто мне помог, ноооо, спасибо тебе, добрый человек!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @CheBoore_ka Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.